# arreglos con itext 5.5 java

Tags: java, itext

Se puede hacer un arreglo de "n" archivos [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) con PdfReader de itext 5.5.9 de java para tener varios pdfs y generar el mismo numero de copias tengo el siguiente codigo que funciona pero solo para 1 a la vez y necesito hacer esto por ejemplo 10 veces a la vez

```
PdfReader leer = new PdfReader("ccna1exp.pdf");  
PdfStamper agua = new PdfStamper(leer, new FileOutputStream("copia.pdf"));
```

Comment: ya intentaste meterlo en un for?

Comment: pero como ago para buscar los archivos y no poner la ruta

Comment: Creo que necesitas ser mas explicito sobre la plataforma que estás ocupando, por ejemplo, existe una biblioteca para leer el contenido de un directorio, una vez leido el directorio, extraes los archivos que existen, una vez leidos haces el ciclo sobre cada uno de ellos para realizar la escritura.